# Will my database call after my Azure function has returned

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-cosmosdb

I have a http trigger Azure Function and I'm trying to optimize it for performance.

Right before it returns I have a CosmosDB await call.

I really don't need to wait until that call returned, it's just logging something informational to the database.

Can I remove the await and running it fully async? Will the database call still go through even after I have called

```
  return new OkObjectResult(results);
```

Or will the function terminate and intermittently the database call will fail

Answer (score 0):

There is not absolute guaranteed that the call to the database will fail. The runtime could shut down for example. And, there is no way of knowing if you don't await the call. I'd probably wait for the call to finish as it won't probably take much time. Otherwise, if it does and you do not want to wait for it put it on a queue and have a seperate function process the queue and write to the database.